# How to Moq Setting an Indexed property

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to use mock to verify that an index property has been set.  Here's a moq-able object with an index:

```
public class Index
{
    IDictionary<object ,object> _backingField 
        = new Dictionary<object, object>();

    public virtual object this[object key]
    {
        get { return _backingField[key]; }
        set { _backingField[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

First, tried using `Setup()`:

```
[Test]
public void MoqUsingSetup()
{
    //arrange
    var index = new Mock<Index>();
    index.Setup(o => o["Key"]).Verifiable();
    // act
    index.Object["Key"] = "Value";
    //assert
    index.Verify();
}
```

...which fails - it must be verifying against `get{}`

So, I tried using `SetupSet()`:

```
[Test]
public void MoqUsingSetupSet()
{
    //arrange
    var index = new Mock<Index>();
    index.SetupSet(o => o["Key"]).Verifiable();
}
```

... which gives a runtime exception:

```
System.ArgumentException : Expression is not a property access: o => o["Key"]
at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.ToPropertyInfo(LambdaExpression expression)
at Moq.Mock.SetupSet(Mock mock, Expression`1 expression)
at Moq.MockExtensions.SetupSet(Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression)
```

What's the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you want to use mocking in this case?  What is it that you are trying to test?  Why not test the Index class directly?

Comment: It's an interface with an index property I'm really wanting to mock.  I asked using a concrete object with a virtual property to simplify the question.

Comment: Ok. Makes more sense :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
[Test]
public void MoqUsingSetup()
{
    //arrange
    var index = new Mock();
    index.SetupSet(o => o["Key"] = "Value").Verifiable();
    // act
    index.Object["Key"] = "Value";
    //assert
    index.Verify();
}
```

You can just treat it like a normal property setter.

Comment: It would be an even better answer (not dissing it) if it catered for the mocked class not having a setter for the index property (as is the case for me)