# How to use Moq to Mock an index property with that has two indexes

Tags: .net, excel, mocking, vsto, moq

This question clearly shows how you can mock an index property with MOQ: [How to Moq Setting an Indexed property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372938/how-to-moq-setting-an-indexed-property)

However, what if you have two index?

For instance, let's say you have a _Worksheet object (from vsto)

```
        var mockWorksheet = new Mock<_Worksheet>();
```

You want to create a property called Cells, such that you can use it like so:

```
        var range = worksheet.Cells[1,1];
```

Note:
The range can be another mock, which could be mocked with:
            var mockRange = new Mock();

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mock property indexers just like anything else.  They're treated just like property accessors, so you'd use `SetupGet`:

```
var mockWorksheet = new Mock<Worksheet>();
var mockRange = new Mock<Range>();
var mockCell = new Mock<Range>();

// Setup the Cells property to return a range     
mockWorksheet.SetupGet(p => p.Cells).Returns(mockRange.Object);

// Setup the range to return an expected "cell"
mockRange.SetupGet(p => p[1, 2]).Returns(mockCell.Object);

var expectedCell = mockWorksheet.Object.Cells[1, 2];

// expectedCell == mockCell.Object
```

Comment: well for me using `mockType.SetupGet(p => p[1]).Returns(mockReturnType.Object);` is throwing `Missing method exception`. instead, I am mocking get_Item method and it is working as expected. `mockType.Setup(p => p.get_Item[1]).Returns(mockReturnType.Object);`